# Why can't I create a new file with mmap of known size?

Tags: python, mmap

I am trying to create a memory mapped file like this

```
size = 83456
self.file = open("/tmp/installer.ipk", "r+b")
self.mm = mmap.mmap(self.file.fileno(), size, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
```

but I get the following exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
  File "./dept_sensor_service.py", line 70, in handle_control
    self.mm = mmap.mmap(self.file.fileno(), size, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
ValueError: mmap length is greater than file size
```

The file `/tmp/installer.ipk` does not exist before I run this. I want the script to create a file called `/tmp/installer.ipk` and filled with 83456 zeros. According to the python documentation for `mmap`:

> If length is larger than the current size of the file, the file is extended to contain
>   length bytes

I've played around with various permissions, but I would think that `'r+b'` for the file and `ACCESS_WRITE` for the map would be correct.

This is on a beaglebone Linux box. BTW, I would have used the `with open(...) as f:` pattern, but I can't in this case as the mmap has to remain open after the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unix version of mmap doesn't grow the file automatically, but you can just write zeros to the file yourself, something like:

```
size = 83456
self.file = open("/tmp/installer.ipk", "w+b")
self.file.write("\0" * size)
self.file.flush()
self.mm = mmap.mmap(self.file.fileno(), size, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
```

Comment: Thanks. I reread the documentation and realized I was reading the Windows section.  Here is another way to write the file to a fixed size, which supposedly is a bit faster:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816059/create-file-of-particular-size-in-python