# Escaping Special Characters (*) in Python subprocess.call()

Tags: python, django

I can't seem to be able to escape these special characters - *.
I'm trying to copy some files using a Python script with the following line

```
subprocess.call(r"mkdir E:\CONTENT\Full1",shell=True)
subprocess.call(r"copy","E:\DATA FOR CONTENT\*.*","E:\CONTENT\Full1",shell=True)
subprocess.call(r"fsutil file createnew ","E:\CONTENT\versionfile.txt","6500000",shell=True)
```

But I get the following error at the 2nd line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic1.py", line 9, in <module>
    subprocess.call(r"copy","E:\DATA FOR CONTENT\*.*","E:\CONTENT\Full1",shell=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 767, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

Also I hate passing it using the CSV Style ("arg1","arg2"...). Is there any way of passing it as a raw string?

Comment: I think you may find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70668916/247696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [*args* should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
subprocess.call(["copy", r"E:\DATA FOR CONTENT\*.*", r"E:\CONTENT\Full1"], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Better don't do this via subprocess. Believe me it's a bad idea.

For simple filesystem copy operations take a look on [python shutil module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html).

For creating new directories use [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs).

For creating files of certain size see [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816059/create-file-of-particular-size-in-python).

Comment: But globbing is hard (no, not really).